# Debugging Go package during development in VS Code

Tags: go

When writing a golang package intended for use by other applications, I'm finding it difficult to figure out the best way to execute it for testing and development purposes.

Normally, the VS Code debugger will start an application, entering at the `main()` function of the `main` package. This library doesn't have such a function or package. Is there a way I can run against this package during the development process, or is my only option to create a separate application and use the package as a local import?

Comment: Write a unit test and debug the test.

Comment: Yeah, write a UT for that and you'll get an option to debug that test.

Comment: Thanks to both of you.